# Having a beginner issue with some basic math functions in Java. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Tags: java

**EDIT: Thanks a ton for everyone who has helped. I can't believe I missed that single typo.**

I'm in need of help for some basic math in Java. I'm trying to create a heat index calculator but when Java compiles runs the program the calculator seems to slip up. I've checked it over multiple times to see the problem but cant find anything. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
    double t = 84.3; //temperature
    int h = 81;    //humidity
    //the following are parts of the heat index formula
    double c1 = -42.379;
    double c2 = 2.04901523;
    double c3 = 10.14333127;
    double c4 = -0.22475541;
    double c5 = -.00683783;
    double c6 = -5.481717E-2;
    double c7 = 1.22874E-3;
    double c8 = 8.5282E-4;
    double c9 = -1.99E-6;
    double hI = c1 + c2 * t + c3 * h + c4 * t * h + c5 * t*t + c6 * h*h + c7 * t*t * h + c8 * t + h*h + c9 * t*t * h*h; //formula for calculating heat index
    System.out.println(hI);
```

So the problem here is that instead of giving me the desired output (heat index), it's returning a very large number (6184.5981258548). Is there an issue with my code? Once again, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what number is ouputing ? Also use brackets around `+` so it processes them in logical order

Comment: 6184.5981258548, my desired output is 95.2

Comment: Make sure that the numbers you are using are actually doubles. You may not get errors but it doesn't mean that the values you are setting for your variables aren't doubles, try adding a "d" or a "D" after the number. You can also add "(double)" in front of them.

Comment: They all look like doubles to me, except for `h` of course. How would casting help in this situation?

Comment: If one of the answers helped you, choose that which helped you the most and accept it (click on the slightly transparent hook left to the answer) :)

Comment: I definitely will, although there's a small waiting period as of now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Heat Index Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_index), then `c8` term should be:

> c<sub>8</sub>TR<sup>2</sup>

But you have for that term:

```
c8 * t + h*h
```

Try

```
c8 * t * h*h
```

Making this change, I get as output:

```
95.21440841480018
```

Comment: Many thanks to both you and user "benji". I can't believe I didn't notice that before submitting.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in `c8*t + h*h`
It should be `c8*t*h*h`